# "Variable does not exists in the current context", but it does

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008

I'm having troubles with a tiny portion of my code.
This error is really pissing me off, because I can't find a reason why is happening.

I have this:

```
string strAux = GetSomeThing();
```

"GetSomeThing()" returns a string value (parsed in JSON format).
But it just doesn't create the variable, neither when I debug it. When I put a breakpoint right in the declaration

```
string strAux;
```

it just doesn't do anything! It won't stop there, it will stop in the next line of the code.

When I quickwatch the variable after it is declared, it says "strAux does not exists in the current context".

Comment: There is nothing to "break" on for `string strAux;` (which is different than having a breakpoint on `string strAux = GetSomeThing();`). Have you tried stepping into `GetSomeThing`?

Comment: Can u show some more code?? It would help answer correctly.

Comment: Is it possible that you have a file from a class library open in the project being debugged, and you are therefore inadvertently changing the code in the class library's file but only rebuilding the project being debugged?

Comment: Do you actually use the value of `strAux` after that line?  Sometimes if a variable is never used, the compiler will just strip it out entirely.